# "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:" and " [mobx] Encountered an uncaught exception.." error every time opening new request tab in postman

Tags: javascript

Whenever I open a new tab in Postman (clicking on the request on the sidebar) 2 errors appear in Cosole and eventually, after 15-20 open tabs postmen gets very slow.

I think the problem of being slow is because of errors  ( it was ok a month ago, but suddenly it began) but I don't know which change made this errors appear
Erroros-
1.

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'id' of 't.getParent(...)' as it is undefined.
    at RequestWorkbenchController.js:827:19
```

2. 

```
[mobx] Encountered an uncaught exception that was thrown by a reaction or observer component, in: 'Reaction[Autorun@57708] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'contextBarQueryParam')
    at r.getContextBarQueryParam (ContextBarService.js:33:56)
    at ContextBar.js:88:65
    at a (mobx.module.js:1945:1)
    at ge (mobx.module.js:1114:1)
```

...

It happnes when oppening every request